# porting from jdk8 to jdk 17 Unable to create message factory for SOAP: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider

Tags: java-17, spring-framework-beans

We moved from jdk8 to jdk 17 started getting this error.
Already using this dependency

Also Wss4j-version 2.2.3  is used.

```
     <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
   <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```